# How can I copy and paste a string of characters into libreoffice calc with one character per cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

```
   ACDAEACCDDAEFFAFCCDFABAADACCCDDAFEDGABEGFCADEHBHACAGHACDEDECDAFAFAFCACDCDEAFCDFCGHDDFF
1  ACD.E..........F......................................................................
2  ...A...CD...F.........................................................................
3  .....AC..D.E.F........................................................................
4  ..........A.....C.DF..................................................................
5  ..............A..C......D.............EG.......H......................................
6  ....................AB................................................................
7  ......................A.....C.D..E.G.........H........................................
8  .......................A..C..D..F.....................................................
9  .........................A.C......D.....F.............................................
10 ...............................A.....B................................................
11 ....................................A....C.DE......GH.................................
12 ..........................................A...B.......................................
13 ................................................AC.....DE.....F.......................
14 ..................................................A........CD.....F...................
15 .....................................................AC..DE.....F.....................
16 .............................................................A.....C..D....F..........
17 ...............................................................A.....C..DE......GH....
18 .................................................................A.....C.....DF.......
19 ....................................................................A.......C.....D.F.
20 ..........................................................................A....C...D.F
   ACDAEACCDDAEFFAFCCDFABAADACCCDDAFEDGABEGFCADEHBHACAGHACDEDECDAFAFAFCACDCDEAFCDFCGHDDFF
                                  1    11   1111 1 11111111111111111111111111211112111212
   11121332234323514544667859897870879710559121172533411553355446375846976877069880779090
   11122333334443332222222334444445544455444344443222333333333334444443444444554443332221
```

I need to do this because it is a figure in a research paper that is referring to columns by column number.
So ideally column labels would be numbers not alpha as well.

I tried Python Pandas, exported to csv and imported that but it's not right:

[image: pandas res]

The column numbers are zero-indexed and the row numbers start at 2 not 1.
Which means following the research paper I have to do a tiny bit of math to index the table.

I tried pandas with option `index=False` when converting dataframe to .csv and got

[image: noIdx]

I deleted the 0 index from the column names, copy and pasted shifting over one spot so the column numbers are correct now but it still starts at row 2.  How can I either zero index the row numbers or change the column names to numbers not alpha?

Comment: Answering your last question (since you already answered your original question) go to `Tools > Options > Libreoffice Calc > Formula` and change "Formula syntax:" to `Excel R1C1`.

Comment: @DavidYockey Thanks so that combined with preprocessing steps in my answer gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

First I copy, pasted the figure from the paper into Jupyter Notebook and added quotation marks, commas etc to make data structures in Python:

```
colNames = "ACDAEACCDDAEFFAFCCDFABAADACCCDDAFEDGABEGFCADEHBHACAGHACDEDECDAFAFAFCACDCDEAFCDFCGHDDFF"

figure2 = {   
1 : "ACD.E..........F......................................................................",
2 : "...A...CD...F.........................................................................",
3 : ".....AC..D.E.F........................................................................",
4 : "..........A.....C.DF..................................................................",
5 : "..............A..C......D.............EG.......H......................................",
6 : "....................AB................................................................",
7 : "......................A.....C.D..E.G.........H........................................",
8 : ".......................A..C..D..F.....................................................",
9 : ".........................A.C......D.....F.............................................",
10 : "...............................A.....B................................................",
11 : "....................................A....C.DE......GH.................................",
12 : "..........................................A...B.......................................",
13 : "................................................AC.....DE.....F.......................",
14 : "..................................................A........CD.....F...................",
15 : ".....................................................AC..DE.....F.....................",
16 : ".............................................................A.....C..D....F..........",
17 : "...............................................................A.....C..DE......GH....",
18 : ".................................................................A.....C.....DF.......",
19 : "....................................................................A.......C.....D.F.",
20 : "..........................................................................A....C...D.F"}
   
srcDig1="                               1    11   1111 1 11111111111111111111111111211112111212"
srcDig2="11121332234323514544667859897870879710559121172533411553355446375846976877069880779090"
numSrcs="11122333334443332222222334444445544455444344443222333333333334444443444444554443332221"

#colNames to list
colNamesArr = [x for x in colNames]

figureD = {k:[x for x in v] for k,v in figure2.items()}
```

Next I use Pandas to output a .csv

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(figureD, orient="index")
```

Then take steps outlined in my question, delete 0 and shift over, plus use @David Yockey's advice.

[image: res]